# chrome extension button highlighted using browser_action basic q

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new to chrome extensions and wondering why I am seeing this behavior.

One a basic chrome extention using browser_action to popup an html page I am wondering why the first button is highlighted or active when I open in.  I am guessing something with browser_action but not sure, wondering if anyone could explain and tell me how to stop this. Here is what I am working with.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
     "default_icon": "test.png",
     "default_popup": "index.html"
  }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

thanks to all in advanced!

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot to describe the weird behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the blue outline around the top button, then this is because by default Chrome adds an outline style to the focused button. And by default it focuses the first button on your popup.

There are a few ways around this.

**Option 1: Change the tab index of all buttons**

The simplest work around.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button tabindex="-1">test
    </button>
    <button tabindex="-1">test
    </button>
    <button tabindex="-1">test
    </button>
    <button tabindex="-1">test
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Option 2: Overwrite the default Chrome style**

This approach overwrites the default Chrome button:focus style. But if you want to add your own button:focus style in future then this issue will reoccur.

Default Chrome style:

```
:focus { /* user agent stylesheet */
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}
```

You can prevent this happening by overwriting the default Chrome style:

```
button:focus {
    outline:0;
}
```

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      button:focus {outline:0;}
    </style>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Option 3: The JavaScript way**

Using JavaScript and the [`blur()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_blur.asp) function, it's possible to remove the focus from the first button. This approach involved a bit more work.

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="popup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
    <button>test
    </button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
function removeInitialFocus() {
    if (event.target.tagName == "BUTTON") {
        event.target.blur();
    }

    document.removeEventListener("focusin", removeInitialFocus);
};

document.addEventListener("focusin", removeInitialFocus);
```